# Creating multiple "public" keys from one private key

Tags: rsa, public-key, pki

Is it possible to create a public key out of a private key, then create another public key from the first public key. And **treat the first public key as a private key** (So you have two levels of private keys). Is the complexity still there? Is it possible to calculate back from the second public key to the first one? or do these keys behave the same as a private/public keypair?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

By definition a public key can't be(come) a secret key. So a cryptosystem such as the one you describe can't be realised. 
But you can have a look at [broadcast encryption](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/broad_abs.html), it may help you !

Comment: We'll, it is possible to realize what's in the question. It is just wholly insecure for the reason pointed in the answer. a public key is not secret, and a private key should be.

Comment: Also note that, in RSA case the public key is small and fixed as 3, 7, 39 etc. Using this as private key will be insecure.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about key derivation, for example Hmac-based key derivation (HKDF). You can derive a private key from a known (private) seed or from another private key, creating a hierarchy of keys. You can provide inputs into the derivation algorithm in addition to the seed/key - for example an identifier, UUID or some entropy. If you want to be able to reproduce the key derivation from the original seed, which seems likely, then all inputs will need to be reproducible.
But as others have said, you cannot derive a private key from a public key, as anyone could do this in order to recreate your private key, which would defeat your security.